# Can I acces my server that is on Virtualbox from another computer that is not connected on same router

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet, remote-access

I am new here, so I hope I will formulate my question correctly.

I am using Windows 7 and I have Oracle Virtualbox, and I have on it running Windows Server 2008. I have set up internet connection (I can acces internet from my Server). The question is, can I somehow acces that Server from another computer (e.g.: from work). (Is there a way to somehow set an IP for that guest so that it can be accesable from the intenet?)

Thank you, in advance.
DjoleHN

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. So W7 is the host, with WS2008 as guest VM.

Does the guest have an IP-address in the same range as the guest? Is the guest VM accessible from other computers in the local entwork?

You need to set portforwarding on your router. Depending on what you want (ssh, http, rdp etc) you need to set the router to forward traffic coming in at those ports to be routed to the guest IP.

For HTTP, Port 80, this is kind of the setup:

```
Work > Home router (port 80) > forward to IP of Guest VM
```

How to setup your router? Look up the model number, google for it plus "port forwarding" and I think it will be easy to do. Then you need to know the IP address at home.

You can test this from home using a free proxy service, which gives you another ip-address. The traffic comes in from another IP, so the router will treat it like it will if you are at work.